# Why can't I rewrite the partition table by testdisk in Windows?

Tags: windows, boot

After some issues with windows my computer I got the next error on boot:

*Error: no such device*

*grub rescue* >

My gparted output:
partition: unallocated
filesystem: unallocated

Fdisk -l

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   314574847   157286400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       314574848   649707567   167566360    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       649709568   708300799    29295616   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       708300810   976784129   134241660    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       708302848   903608319    97652736   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       903614464   917284847     6835192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       917284864   976769023    29742080    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So I ran testdisk, it found the right partitions

```
Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60802 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 19581  96 35  314572800 [Programs]
 P HPFS - NTFS          19581  96 36 40442 108 34  335132720 [Data]
 P Linux                40442 140 19 44089 174 53   58591232
 L Linux                44089 207 23 56247   4 13  195305472
 L Linux Swap           56247 101 47 57098  86 60   13670384
 L HPFS - NTFS          57098  87 14 60801  15 14   59484160 [New Volume]
```

Then I pressed enter to write this partition table, it says succeed, reboot required.

After reboot, my partition table is still "gone" (Gparted says).

So, testdisk didn't do the job??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my 500GB external hard drive. It happened when the drive is in operation but the USB became loose.

I tried testdisk but when i opened Disk Manager, it showed my disk as RAW with 100% free space. So i ran checkdisk:

> chkdsk /f e:

where `e:` is the drive letter

It managed to recover my NTFS partition and Disk Manager shows the correct used space.
The only problem I now have is that the disk is inaccessible :(